# Creating templates in Django of Multiple Models with ForeignKey field

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have two models like these:

```
class NominaEnc(models.Model):
    G1 = "PERSONAL"
    G2 = "SUPERVISOR"
    G3 ="AUXILIAR"

    GRUPO_CHOICES = (
        (G1, 'PERSONAL'),
        (G2, 'SUPERVISOR'),
        (G3, 'AUXILIAR'),
    )

    fecha_nomina= models.DateField()
    planta =models.ForeignKey(PlantaNomina,to_field='descripcion_planta',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    area=models.ForeignKey(AreaNomina, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='descripcion_area')
    linea =models.ForeignKey(lineaNomina, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='descripcion_linea')
    grupo=models.CharField(choices=GRUPO_CHOICES, max_length=30, blank=True, null =True)
    supervisor=models.ForeignKey(SupervisorNomina, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        to_field='nombre_supervisor')
    semana = models.IntegerField(default=1 )
    plantilla = models.IntegerField(default=0)



    def __str__(self):
        return'{} {} {} {} {}'.format(self.semana, self.area, self.linea, self.grupo, 
        self.supervisor)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural ="Encabezados Nomina"
        verbose_name = "Encabezado Nomina"

class NominaDet(models.Model):

    nomina = models.ForeignKey(NominaEnc, related_name='detalles' ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    concepto=models.ForeignKey(ConceptoNomina, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='concepto')
    cantidad =models.FloatField(default=0.0)


    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.nomina,self.concepto)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural ="Detalles Nomina"
        verbose_name = "Detalle Nomina"
```

the Views I have are:

```
class NominaList( generic.ListView):
    model=NominaEnc
    template_name='nomina/nomina_list.html'
    context_object_name='nomina'

class NominaCompletaList(generic.ListView):
    template_name='nomina/nomina_completa.html'
     context_object_name='nomina'
    queryset = NominaEnc.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(NominaCompletaList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['detalles'] = NominaDet.objects.all()
        context['encabezado'] = self.queryset
        return context
```

and the url are:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('nomina/', NominaList.as_view(), name="nomina_list"),
path('nomina_completa/', NominaCompletaList.as_view(), name="nomina_completa")
]
```

In NominaList View I just list the fields of NominaEnc, and in NominaCompleta View I am trying to show NominaEnc (header) and NominaDet (details of each NominaEnc record).

however I dont know how to create the template for NominaCompleta View. Any help to do the template (html) and call all fields of booth models will be very appreciated.

Comment: I found a similar question, however, they did not create the template

Comment: In your models, one `NominaEnc` can have multiple `NominaDet` (since you have a one-to-many relationship with your ForeignKey). So if in your template you have one `nomina_enc` instance (e.g. in a for-loop), then you can do `{% for det in nomina_enc.detalles.all %}` and then for example print `{{ det.cantidad }}`.

Comment: Thank you it worked!!! If you put as n answer i will acept it. @dirkgroten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your models, one `NominaEnc` can have multiple `NominaDet` (since you have a one-to-many relationship with your ForeignKey).

So if in your template you have one `nomina_enc` instance (e.g. in a for-loop), then you can do

```django
{% for det in nomina_enc.detalles.all %}
    {{ det.cantidad }}
{% endfor %}
```

or whatever else you need to do inside the loop.

Comment: Once I have the two models do you know how can I export the data to an excel file?